# is it possible to transfer table data from one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to copy data from a table to another table?.

here is my example. i have two tables, warehouse and showroom

my warehouse table has (product_id and stock_quantity) and my showroom table has (product_id(fk from warehouse), stock_transferred )..

for example in warehouse table

```
product_id     stock_quantity
1              10
2              20
```

how can I transfer product_id(1)with stock_quantity(5) in showroom table and still retain the data in warehouse table?

so after transferring data my warehouse table becomes these:

```
product_id     stock_quantity
1              5
2              20
```

and my showroom table becomes these:

```
product_id     stock_transferred
1              5
```

how can i do these in a php form?for example i have a text input in which the user can specify how many stocks he will transfer to showroom table.

sorry I cant explain well Im not good in english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRAN 

INSERT INTO showroom
SELECT product_id, @ValueToBeReduced FROM warehouse 
WHERE product_id = 1

-- error handling

UPDATE warehouse 
SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity - @ValueToBeReduced
INNER JOIN showroom
ON warehouse.product_id = showroom.product_id
AND showroom.product_id = 1

-- error handling

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: There is no 'PHP form'. You pass the above SQL to the appropriate DB functions from your PHP.

Comment: i mean how can i implement these together with a php form?. for example users have a form in which they can choose what products and how many stocks they can transfer to showroom.

Comment: what do you mean with '@ValueToBeReduced'?.. is it a column?

Comment: @kester martinez - @ValueToBeReduced - is the value you want to reduce the stock quantity by. Ideally this value would be entered in by a user from the UI. This value will be passed as a parameter to the SQL which uses it both to reduce the warehouse entry and insert entry into the showroom table

Answer (score 0):

You can use [insert into(select...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert-select.html)